# Ios webview with capacitor, set safe areas

Tags: ios, cordova, viewport, iphone-x, capacitor

Using capacitor to build an app in ios. In ios the webview covers the whole screen, for iphone-x that means the notch will be included and content will go behind it, like the picture on the right. But i want the picture on the left, black bars on 'no go areas'.

[image: ex]

The expected solution (html/css) for this would be to set correct viewport and use the 'safe-area'insert-?', se: https://css-tricks.com/the-notch-and-css/
But for the webview in ios the 'safe-area'insert' will always be 0, that is how it works => this solution is useless.

How can i solve this? Can i change the webview to not cover the whole screen, without changing in the capacitor-framework?

Comment: I did solve this in a dirty way, checking the screen width / heigt (window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight) and applying padding. Intresting width x heights: 375x812, 414x896, 414x736, 375x667.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? Looks like lots of people have the same question!

Answer (score 1):

There is a CSS  variable preset by capacitor you can use to set the padding or a margin for example.

```
html {
    --ion-safe-area-top: env(safe-area-inset-top);
    --ion-safe-area-bottom: env(safe-area-inset-bottom);
    --ion-safe-area-left: env(safe-area-inset-left);
    --ion-safe-area-right: env(safe-area-inset-right);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a compatible Cordova plugin `cordova-plugin-safearea`

```
npm i -D cordova-plugin-safearea
npx cap sync
```

With this installed, you can request the safe margin area over the cordova/capacitor bridge:

```
// Types for clarity
type SafeArea = {
  top: string,
  bottom: string,
}

window.plugins.safearea.get(
  (result: SafeArea) => {
    // elegantly set the result somewhere in app state
  },
  (error: any) => {
    // maybe set some sensible fallbacks?
  }
);
```

You could use these values to specify extra padding on the body, or on your header / bottom-menu components

The docs say it returns the values as Numbers, but it seems to me they are actually strings (consider parseFloat before doing math with them).

---

I have just implemented this in React (running the getter in React.useLayoutEffect); the project is wrapped in Capacitor and have tested on two iOS devices with different ingenious Apple notch screen formats (iPhone 8 and iPhone 11 Pro).

Refer to the documentation for more at https://github.com/rickgbw/cordova-plugin-safearea

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just set the safe area like this like in any normal website using the [env()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/env) mechanism:

```
body {
    /* Other styles above... */
    padding: env(safe-area-inset-top) env(safe-area-inset-right) env(safe-area-inset-bottom) env(safe-area-inset-left);
}
```

(I'm using a plain Capacitor app without Ionic.)